# Are starting an Activity and Launching an Application the same?

Tags: android, android-activity

What I want ask is, assume I'm in some `BroadCastReciever`'s `onRecieve()` method and I use context to start an `Activity` which is a Launcher Activity of a different Application. Will it work? Are both this way and Application launching by just clicking on icon the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is NO.

1. You can launch the launcher activity of the app of which `BroadCastReciever`'s `onRecieve()` method you are getting the call not the other app's launcher activity.
2. You can launch another application thru its package name from anywhere of your app.

> Are both this way and Application launching by just clicking on icon the same?

Yes as you are getting the application launched.